# how do I make my textbox display this value?

Tags: c#

my code is supposed to give me the amount of Mondays in a month in a textbox but it keeps telling me that 'Form1.MondaysInMonth(DateTime)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context, does anybody know how to fix this? I am pretty new to coding so please tell me if I am doing something completely wrong.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = MondaysInMonth.ToString();
        }
        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string month = textBox2.Text;
        }
        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string year = textBox3.Text;
        }
        private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        
        }

        private void Label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public static int MondaysInMonth(DateTime thisMonth)
        {
            int mondays = 0;
            int month = thisMonth.Month;
            int year = thisMonth.Year;
            int daysThisMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
            DateTime beginingOfThisMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < daysThisMonth; i++)
                if (beginingOfThisMonth.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                    mondays++;
            return mondays;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To call a method you need parenthesys. _MondaysInMonth(....).ToString();_ and of course you should pass the parameter expected by the method (the month's date)

Comment: your function define with a datetime argument .But you call the function without  argument .instated of function call just var days =   DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you want the user to enter the month into textBox2, the year into textBox3, and the days of that month/year combination to appear in textBox1.  The results are calculated, so really you should use a Label instead of a TextBox, but I  suppose you could just make the textBox1 read only.

I'll assume that the month and year are being entered in as a NUMBER.  The first thing you need to do is convert that string representation of a number into a valid integer.  A common approach is to use [int.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__).  Once you have both user entries converted to valid numbers you can then call your function and place the results into your output control.

Since you need a valid month AND a valid year, I'd put the validation code into a common method and call that from both the textBox2 and textBox3 TextChanged() events.  You should NOT have a textBox1 TextChanged() event at all.

This might look something like this:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    validateMonthYear();
}

private void textBox3_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    validateMonthYear();
}

private void validateMonthYear()
{
    int month, year;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out month) && int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out year))
    {
        int days = DaysInMonth(month, year, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        if (days > 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = days.ToString();
            return;
        }                                                 
    }
    textBox1.Text = "{Invalid}";
}

public int DaysInMonth(int month, int year, DayOfWeek day)
{
    int days = 0;
    try
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
        int daysThisMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
        for (int i = 1; i <= daysThisMonth; i++, dt = dt.AddDays(1))
            if (dt.DayOfWeek == day)
                days++;

    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    return days;
}
```

Note that in your original `DaysInMonth()` function, you were actually SKIPPING the very first day of the month so it would never be taken into account.